# What is Tanam in Music?

Tags: terminology, indian-classical

What is Tanam in Indian music ?
Is tanam used in Cinema music ?

i.e After Pallavi of a song a piece of music playing it might be 8 bar or 16 bar etc. Is it Tannam ?

Comment: Looks like a type of improvisation, also spelled *tanam*: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragam_Thanam_Pallavi

Answer (score 1):

Tanam is one of the methods of improvising a raga(which is called manodharma) in carnatic music. There are various tanams like vadhya tanam, aja tanam, gaja tanam etc. Tanam comes after the raga but before the pallavi of a song. To sing a tanam one should have good hold on singing and experience. It is rarely being sung by any musician.

Answer (score 1):

Thanam is a specific kind of improvisation in Carnatic music. It is rhythmic, but not bound by meter (Thalam). Tempo varies within the performance. Unmeasured pauses are allowed between phrases/sections.

> After Pallavi of a song a piece of music playing it might be 8 bar or 16 bar etc. Is it Tannam ?

No, that would be an *interlude*.

Here's an example of Thanam: